Trying to install terminal-diary github program through pip in Powershell and VS Code, not working :(
I tried running the following code (as recommended on the how-to-install directions from the terminal-diary github)
git clone git@github.com:dorisjlee/terminal-diary.git
cd terminal-diary
python setup.py install

in my Windows Powershell:
PS C:\Users\edene> git clone git@github.com:dorisjlee/terminal-diary.git
Cloning into 'terminal-diary'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
PS C:\Users\edene> cd terminal-diary
cd : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\edene\terminal-diary' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1

cd terminal-diary

  + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\edene\terminal-diary:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundExcep
tion
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand





I tried opening the first line in VS code too but it returned this error:
Cloning into 'terminal-diary'...
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
PS C:\Users\edene\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\terminal-diary> 


https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

If you don't want to configure access with SSH why not use HTTPS? The repository is public, https access doesn't need authentication.

@phd Hi! How would I configure access with HTTPS? Do you have a tutorial or list of steps?

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+https , https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#URLS

git clone https://github.com/dorisjlee/terminal-diary.git — please note the difference between :dorisjlee/terminal-diary.git and /dorisjlee/terminal-diary.git (colon vs slash).
